# Log-In module with SQL Server not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have created two form for Login module. One for the admins and one for the customers.

Admin:

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LEGIONPC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from tbAdmin where admin_id=' " + txtUsername.Text + " ' and admin_password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con)
        Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        sda.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
             MessageBox.Show("Correct.", "Log-In")
        Else
             MessageBox.Show("Invalid.", "Log-In")
        End If
```

Customer:

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LEGIONPC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from tbLogin where username=' " + txtUsername.Text + " ' and pass='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con)
        Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        sda.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Correct.", "Log-In")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid.", "Log-In")
        End If
```

They are basically just the same, except that both of them are in different form and are based on different tables. But for some reason, the Customer log in is not working, even though the inputs are correct and matches the records in database, it always shows it's invalid.

In database, `tbAdmin`'s primary key is `admin_id` and `tbCustomer`'s primary key is `username`.

Is it possible that it's kind of interrupting the connection because they basically all have the same variable name? But they're in different form and admin log in is perfectly fine.

I would like to apologize, I am new to connecting vb.net to sql.

Comment: Can I ask why you're putting application data in the `master` database? And inlining tainted user inputs into your SQL queries instead of using `SqlParameter`s? And still storing plaintext passwords instead of salting-and-hashing them or moving away from passwords altogether?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm sorry. I'm not really familiar with connecting SQL Server and VB.Net, so I just kept following YouTube tutorials. In my class, we only use Oracle Apex's SQL commands or Excel. That's all we've been doing, and this is the first time the professor stepped up her game and made us do a project she hasn't discussed (or ever simulate the connection) and probably won't discuss. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Switch to user database parameters in place of in line sql. Run the two sql queries directly against the database and see what the result is.

Comment: are you hitting any error or you simply just can't login?

Comment: @YatFeiLeong simply cannot login. [ https://ibb.co/7K4YPgh ] -- here's the output.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing I notice is you leave a space between the colon
Try this

```
"select * from tbLogin where username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' and pass='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
```

Also if you do not want it to be case sensitive you always use 'like'

```
"select * from tbLogin where username like '" & txtUsername.Text & "' and pass like '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
```